# Creating a balanced spell

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance, homebrew

I'm currently playing a level 6 warlock (pact of the seeker) in a campaign right now. I want to develop a new spell in game. This is the spell that I'm trying to create:

> **Name**: Xanlin's Secret Bookshelf
>
> **Level**: 4th level conjuration
>
> **Casting Time**: 1 action
>
> **Duration**: Instantaneous
>
> **Range**: Touch
>
> **Components**: V S M (An exquisite bookshelf, 4 feet tall by 3 feet wide by 1 foot deep, constructed from rare materials worth at least 5,000 gp, and a Tiny replica made from the same materials worth at least 50 gp)
>
> You hide a bookshelf, and all its contents, on the Ethereal Plane. You must touch the bookshelf and the miniature replica that serves as a material component for the spell. The bookshelf can contain up to 25 books or scrolls of varying sizes.
>
> While the bookshelf remains on the Ethereal Plane, you can use an action and touch the replica to recall the  bookshelf. It appears in an unoccupied space on the ground within 5 feet of you. You can send the bookshelf back to the Ethereal Plane by using an action and touching both the bookshelf and the replica.

I have two questions for this:

1. Is this spell balanced? If not, what changes would you recommend?
2. Are there any rules for a player creating a spell in game? I'm vaguely aware of the rules in the DMG for DMs creating spell, but are there any for players? If not, are there any places I can look to for guidance?

I based this spell off of Leomund's Tiny Chest with minor modifications. IT doesn't expire, but I figured that since you can only store books/scrolls and not treasure that is fine balance-wise.

Comment: What is the goal of this spell? Is this to create a means of 'storing' spellbooks in a safe place?

Comment: I think you would be better served splitting up your two questions. Probably take the first one and post it as a seperate [tag:homebrew-review] question as you already have gotten an answer to the second posted here.

Comment: Yeah - "Is this specific homebrew balanced?" and "What official rules exist for players creating spells in-game?" are two entirely different questions, and should be asked separately. You should edit one of them out of this post and ask it separately, as suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Talk to your DM

Balance is a curious thing, and can be very different for different campaigns, with different house rules, different parties, with different abilities.

With that said, perhaps I can give you a few tips for suggesting a new spell to your dungeon master.

#### Explain the similarities and differences

I can clearly see the similarities and differences here from the base spell, make sure you have a straight-forward conversation with your DM about what's the same and what's different.

#### How and why is this happening?

If your character is creating a spell in-universe, why are they doing this and how do they have the means to do so? Story and flavour are always important.

#### State your intentions

Explain *why* you want to create this spell. If you have written it with an exploit that your DM does not anticipate this will likely be a bad time for everyone. Make sure both you and your DM know the intention of gaining the home-brew spell so that your DM can plan accordingly (as they would be able to if you chose a spell from official material).

#### Prepare to compromise or walk away

It is within the DMs power to say no, and not allow this spell within your game. Be prepared to compromise if your DM requests changes, or to walk away if you can't come to an agreement.

Comment: I like your general approach, and generally agree.  It may be helpful to the question asker to refer to where in the DMG the "create a spell" section is.